# Change Titlebar icon on WinUI 3

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winui-3, ico

I'm developing an application to understand how the tool works and I need to change the TitleBar icon, but when I set an icon it has a white background and not a transparent background.

[Current TitleBar]
[image]

How could I change this??

My code looks like this:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var buttonThickness = new Thickness();
    var listThickness = new Thickness();
    var emptyTasksBlockTextThickness = new Thickness();

    emptyTasksBlockTextThickness.Top = 12;
    buttonThickness.Left = 16;
    listThickness.Top = 12;

    myButton.Margin = buttonThickness;
    tasks.Margin = listThickness;
    emptyTasksBlockText.Margin = emptyTasksBlockTextThickness;

    this.AppWindow.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 31, 41, 55);
    this.AppWindow.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 31, 41, 55);
    // this.AppWindow.TitleBar.ForegroundColor = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0, 31, 41, 55);

    this.AppWindow.Title = "ToDo Application";
    this.Activated += MainWindow_Activated;
}

private void MainWindow_Activated(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.WindowActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    string icon = Path.Combine(
        Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path,
        "Icon.ico"
    );


    this.AppWindow.SetIcon(icon);
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="videodownloader.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:videodownloader"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBox 
            x:Name="textInput" 
            Width="500" 
            KeyDown="TextBlock_KeyDown" 
            PlaceholderText="Type your task here" 
            Header="Enter with task" 
         />
            <local:CustomButton
            PointerEntered="myButton_PointerEntered" 
            PointerExited="myButton_PointerExited" 
            x:Name="myButton"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            Click="myButton_Click"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI"
            FontWeight="SemiBold"
            
            CornerRadius="4"
         >
                Add Task
            </local:CustomButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="emptyTasksBlockText" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Nenhuma tarefa adicionada ainda!</TextBlock>
        <ListView x:Name="tasks" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemResource}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TaskItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name, Mode=OneTime}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <Button Click="removeItem_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DataContext="{Binding name}">Remover</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I want to make the background of my icon the same color as the titlebar

Comment: Make sure the .ico uses transparency (RGB+Alpha Channel).

Comment: There is no issue. [WinUI-Gallery](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/1d237241853b788e3f551a5a2de6f47fc5693a2f/WinUIGallery/Navigation/NavigationRootPage.xaml#L63) also customizes the title bar while [Its PNG](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/blob/1d237241853b788e3f551a5a2de6f47fc5693a2f/WinUIGallery/Assets/Tiles/TitlebarLogo.png) does not use transparency.

Answer (score 0):

As @SimonMourier said, make sure your source uses transparency. The [WinUI3_CustomCaption](https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_CustomCaption/tree/f4e49d3885b64ea415649e1b2ac9990542e3c690) sample works fine. Of course, Its source uses transparency. See https://github.com/castorix/WinUI3_CustomCaption/blob/f4e49d3885b64ea415649e1b2ac9990542e3c690/Assets/Butterfly.png